# build Debian package "chromium 108" on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, compiling, dpkg, packaging, reproducible-build

I am trying to build `chromium 108` for Debian Buster. The package only exists for Debian Bullseye, so on my Debian Buster build machine, I need to change the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to bullesyse and download sources:

```
apt-get source chromium
```

After that I change `sources.list` back to buster.

I cd to the directory and try `dpkg-buildpackage`:

```
cd chromium-108.0.5359.94
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

Few build dependencies where missing, but I could install them from Buster repository.

Only 2 packages do not exist in buster:

```
generate-ninja
libpipewire-0.3-dev
```

I was able to install `generate-ninja` from `Bullseye` without problems, and grepping the tree for `pipewire` shows in `./debian/changelog`

- Enable pipewire support in webrtc (closes: #954824).

which looks like some non-essential feature, so I will try to remove `pipewire` from build dependencies:

remove line 66 from `debian/control`:

```
-libpipewire-0.3-dev,
```

and remove line 91 from `debian/rules`

```
-rtc_use_pipewire=true \
```

Now I can start the build process again and it runs for a while:

```
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

until I get following error:

```
5546/54816] ACTION //third_party/blink/renderer/bindings:generate_bindings_all(//build/toolchain/linux/unbundle:default)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:125: override_dh_auto_build-arch] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/chromium-108.0.5359.94'
make: *** [debian/rules:112: binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

Full output here: https://ctxt.io/2/AACQ8LyZEw

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `Error: yargs parser supports a minimum Node.js version of 12. Read our version support policy: https://github.com/yargs/yargs-parser#supported-nodejs-versions`. Is Node.js installed?

Comment: @Freddy - yes, but nodejs version 10.24.0 The `debian/control` file has `nodejs` as build dependency but does not specify any particular version.

Comment: `debian/control` is written in the context of a specific release, and doesn’t need to specify a minimum version for dependencies where the minimum version is always satisfied in that release. Bullseye has `nodejs` 12.22.5, so `debian/control` can rely on NodeJS 12 or later without specifying the version. It’s up to you to adjust things for Buster.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - do you know what is the latest chromium version that can be compiled on Debian 10 ?

Comment: @400theCat I have no idea.